# Angular 4 add transition on button hover

Tags: css, angular, css-transitions

I'm trying to achieve same transition effect on buttons like here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#outline-buttons. I need much more customization than bootstrap offers so I trying to make it by myself using css styles / effects.

This is how I display buttons:

```
<div class="container">
      <div *ngFor="let cat of categories">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <button [ngStyle]="matchButtonColor(cat)" (mouseover)="transition()" class="btn " type="button" (click)="openDialog(cat)"> {{cat.name}} </button>
            <categories *ngIf="cat.children" [categories]="cat.children" (category)="onClickChild($event)"></categories>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

Two functions in component (yes i know that transition effect is pointless in this function because it doesn't affects on-hover):

```
  matchButtonColor(category: AdminCategory) {
    var s = {
      'background-color': 'white',
      'border-color': '#8064A2',
      'color': '#8064A2',
      'transition': 'color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out'
    }
    return s;
  }

  transition(){
    console.log("aasdasd");
  }
```

Currently I got this. Now I would like to get this transition effect on hover. Is there any way to make it works? I can't just put it into .css file because I need to create colors dynamically (it depends on `cat` value).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably achieve it by setting `hoverFlag` to true on `mouseover` and reset it to false on `mouseout`. Then have two methods - one for hover state and other for normal state. (You can just have a single method and pass the flag based on your requirement).

```
<button [ngStyle]="hoverFlag ? matchHoverButtonColor(cat) : matchButtonColor(cat)" (mouseover)="hoverFlag = true" (mouseout)="hoverFlag = false" class="btn " type="button" (click)="openDialog(cat)"> {{cat.name}} </button>
```

So, If `hoverFlag` is true then `matchHoverButtonColor(cat)` will be called. Otherwise, `matchButtonColor(cat)` will be called.

Comment: hmm it doesn't works, styles on hover not applying the button

Comment: If you can create a plunker with your implementation would be good to debug the issue

Comment: sorry my bad, it works! I just didn't return any value in onHover function... thanks :)

Comment: Happy that it helped you!